# How can SQLServer represent 0.2 as FLOAT

Tags: sql-server, floating-point, computer-science, floating-accuracy

```
DECLARE @f as float

SELECT @f = 0.2

SELECT @f
```

The above code returns

```
----------------------
0.2

(1 row(s) affected)
```

No surprise there. [Except that floating-point cannot represent `0.2` exactly.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

So what is SQLServer doing here? Is it using floating-point with a base of 10? I was of the understanding that it always dealt with floating-point in base 2 (as floating-point with base 10 would basically be `DECIMAL`?).

Is it doing some rounding?

Comment: A minor point, but `0.2` is a decimal constant. `0.2E0` is a float constant. It doesn't affect the question thoguh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`float` is accurate to 15 significant figures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) so `0.2` will usually come out as `0.2`

The techniques mentioned in your link mitigate (but may not eliminate) loss of precision for values like this with few digits

But with larger numbers, precision is lost

```
DECLARE @f as float

SELECT @f = 0.1234567890123456E0
SELECT @f

SELECT @f = 1.000000000000023E0
SELECT @f
```

Comment: So what will it actually be storing to represent this? Is it using base 2?

Comment: So it will store `10 (b2)` to represent `2 (b10)` and also `1 (b2)` to represent `1 (b10)` to shift the *decimal* point 1 place?

Comment: @ElRonnoco: Floating point uses a mantissa and exponent. So `0.2(b10)` will be a mantissa of `2(b10)` and exponent of `-1(b10)`. Or `2 times (10 to power of -1)`. But in binary equivalent, whatever that is. So `0.2(b10)` will be stored as `x(b2) times (2 to power of y(b2))`